# Error in the sentence: "the people election delegates to an assembly"

Tags: meaning

I have met the following sentence in an English test:

> In a **representative** **democracy**, the people **election** delegates to an
>   **assembly**.

I have to find an error in the sentence, but it looks pretty OK.

Could anybody explain what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with *election*. *Election* is a noun:

> a formal and organized choice by vote of a person for a political office or other position.

The verb, *elect* is required:

> choose (someone) to hold public office or some other position by voting.

Comment: I have though that "the people election" is a subject here and "delegates" is an action(verb). Am I wrong?

Comment: I was thinking on *delegates*, since *people* is plural so I paraphrased that as *people election **delegate*** (...)

Comment: @arsast yes, you're wrong. _Delegates_ can be a noun, 'a person sent or authorized to represent others, in particular an elected representative sent to a conference.', or a verb, 'entrust (a task or responsibility) to another person, typically one who is less senior than oneself.'. You seem to have confused the two. Delegates are the people elected to an assembly.

Comment: Oh I was thinking on *delegate* as a verb.

Comment: @ale _people_ is plural, _the people_ is singular, ie it is a single group.

Comment: What? 'the people' is singular?